# Microsoft office 2007 and endnote

Tags: ms-word

I have a problem with a document I am writing. I used endnote to place ~50 references, and I would like to type in a summary in between the citations.

Problem: Word will not seem to use it's auto editing features, and everything is highlighted in grey (just like the citations).

Any ideas how to stop this? (I believe it has something to do with field codes)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my question, do not ever do an annotated bibliography this way! I was able to work around this by converting the document to plain text, then copying a section into another word document which then enables the editing features.